# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: asp.net, mysql

We are getting this error when updating site on new server. We are using mysql with asp.net project in visual studio 2010.

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider in Visual Studio 2010 Professional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928361/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

The MySql provider specified in your connection string is not installed on the server.  Install it.  It'll be whatever is installed on your development machine.

For a better answer, please post the part of your connection string that shows which provider/version to use.

Comment: How do you install this?  And which one exactly?