# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, datasource

Why am I getting "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider" when trying to setup a new datasource in Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

My stats:

- Windows 7 64bit 16gig RAM
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- SQL Server 2008  (server A, full admin rights)
- SQL Server 2008  (server B, full admin rights)

I have started a test ASP.NET application and when I try to add a new data source, I get:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

I have .NET 4 installed.

When I build the connection and click "Test Connection" it tests successful.  SQL Server Management Studio connects just fine and I have verified the credentials on everything.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I have seen reports of people having and additional, self terminating  node in the machine.config file. Removing it resolved their issue. machine.config is found in `\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\vXXXX\Config`. You could have a multitude of config files based on how many versions of the framework are installed, including 32 and 64 bit variants.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" ... />
        <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" ... />
        <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
        <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
        <add name="IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider" invariant="IBM.Data ... />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" ... />     
    </DbProviderFactories>

    <DbProviderFactories/>  //remove this one!
</system.data>
```

Comment: THAT WORKED!!!!!!  Thanks!!  I actually saw that earlier but it didn't occur to me to remove that `remove this one!` copy.  Plus, I have four machine.config files.  One in version 2 and version 4 for both 32 and 64bit.  I had to change all four.  Thanks so much!  +100000

Comment: Note on my fix - even though my machine is 64bit with .NET framework 4 -> it was the removal of the IBM.Data.DB2... references in machine.config under .NET 2 that fixed the bug with SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: I tried this fix and now VS2015 closes at the splash screen and no applications written in .Net4.0 will start.  Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: I can't edit my previous comment, but fixed it by copying these files from another PC.  I should also point out that installing Setup_NpgsqlDdexProvider.exe found here [link](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases) caused this mayhem for me in the first place.

Comment: this issue appeared in visual studio 2019 after i installed visauls studio 2022. 
thank you.

Comment: Genius! SSMS suddenly tripped on this error. In my case (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config) there was a duplicate there: <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" etc...>
Likely added by a MySQL client install. Would have been nice if .NET error actually referred to the physical file to show this!

Answer (score 20):

I like the other suggestions but I would rather not update the machine.config for a single application. I suggest that you just add it to the web.config / app.config. Here is what I needed to use the MySql Connector/NET that I "bin" deployed.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories >
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: There are project types that do not have `web.config`.

Comment: Also worth noting that if a different version of a provider *is* installed on the machine, you would need to add a `<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />` to the above snippet.

Answer (score 8):

It works for me thank you. I had this issue when I installed .Net Framework 4.7.1, somehow `DbProviderFactories` settings under `System.Data` in machine config got wiped-out. It started working after adding the necessary configuration settings as shown below `DataProviderFactories`

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the Data provider entry for MySQL was "simply" missing in the machine.config file described above (though I had installed the MySQL connector properly)

```
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
```

Don't forget to put the right Version of your MySQL on the Entry

Comment: In my case, this row was missing, and reinstalling MySQL .Net Connector actually added the missing row for me... :-).     P.s. I'm using [this link](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mysql/Downloads/Connector-Net/) (no registration needed)

Answer (score 2):

I thought my issue was due to my machine.config per answers I found online but the culprit turned out to be in the project's web.config that was clearing out the DbProviderFactories.

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <clear />
       ...
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Though this specifically wasn't my issue, it lead me to the <DbProviderFactories> where someone had set it to remove the provider. Go figure??? It's a project I'm having to take over so I'm just having to sift through the issues. My web.config had this: <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />. Commented that out and bingo, I was back working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with version 6.7.4 and resolved it by installing version 6.5.6.

My setup is Win 2008 R2 SP1 Data Center edition, SQL Server 2008 R2 with Business Intelligence Development Studio (VS2008). Very basic install.

When I was installing 6.7.4, i could not even see the MySQL provider as a choice. However, when i looked into the machine.config file, I saw references for MySQL role provider etc, but no entry was added in the .

Comment: This was my issue as well and it was resolved by installing "MySQL for Visual Studio integration" as instructed here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

I'm honstely not quite sure what it is, but they removed it from the connector package where it was previously.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem in visual studio 2019 and it resolved by searching in the searchbar inside visual studio: manage NuGet packages > oracle.ManagedDataAccess (first result) install it. and then it should works!

Answer (score 0):

its solved. Use nuget and search for the "ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client".

and install the package. it will resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for vs2022 I found that installing this fixed my issue https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30709

Comment: I am getting (when following that link): "Internet Explorer was retired on June 15, 2022" ?  So, WHAT, did you actually install ?