# Entity Framework Nuget Update to V6: No Provider Found

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

After update my MVC4 application (.NET 4.0) with NuGet Package Manager from entity framework (Code First) 5 to 6, I get follow error on start of the application:

- No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
  invariant name 'System.Data.OleDb'.

But in the web.config, I have only the SqlClient Provider registered:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db1;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
<parameters>
<parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
 </providers></entityFramework>
```

Why appears a Error for the OleDB Provider?

Note:
I have this problem in solutions, on which the mvc project acess to the DB over a second project(library). Both project have the EF Packeage installed.

Comment: Did you try [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928361/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-in-visual-studio-2010)?

Comment: If I create on the same machine a new mvc4 application with the template and update the entity Framework to V6, then I have no problems. So I think, the machine.config is not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I deinstalled Nuget-Packages, which used EF5: Miniprofiler, Glimpse EF5.
The error disappeared.