# Asp.Net 5 "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, entity-framework

I have 2 projects in a solution one asp.net 5, and one class library project containing EFModel. I used install-package to install :
 "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
 "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3"
on both projects and have the connection string in both classlibrary\app.config and wwwroot\web.config I searched the internet some said placing:

```html
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>​
```

in web.config solves the problem, I have this section in app.config and when I try to place this in web.config file I get angularjs inject error. My entity framework code gets me the error:
"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure ... 
And I am not able to solve this, help Please.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC 5 or ASP.NET 5(vNext)? If so then I guess you need to add frameworks dependency in project.json.

Comment: I have these dependencies already in Project.json file:  "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3"

Comment: Not sure how much this link is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111583/entity-framework-ado-net-sql-data-client-provider-not-found?rq=1

Comment: @mz1378 If you are targeting Core framework, try targeting full version.

Comment: I have: "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "DataAccess": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    } in my project json.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Solved my problem as bellow:
Although I added *EntityFramework* and *EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact* using Nuget once for every project in the solution and my project.json says that:
 **"EntityFramework": "6.1.3", "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3"**,
But I noticed that Visual Studio did a nasty job of referencing all packages from the **ClassLibrary** project, So I copied all the assemblies from classlibrary project's bin to MainProject bin and add a reference to all of them through browsing, And Finally copied required Auto Generated configurations from ClassLibrary's app.config to MainProject's web.config and Problem Solved.

Comment: Thanks for sharing really helpful ! for me installing EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact using Nuget Manager was sufficient .

Answer (score 1):

usually this error occurs due to the Entityframework.
follow the following

1. Add `entityframeworkcore from the NuGet,`
2. Add `entityframeworkdesign.`
3. Add `entityframework.sqlserver.compact`

last give a rebuild for the solution
the above method worked for me as I also found that issue.