# ASP.NET Inserting data into entity with Azure SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET if someone could explain why this doesn't work or how to set it up correctly would be great

This code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] User account)
    {
        Accounts newAccount = new Accounts { FirstName = account.FirstName, LastName = account.LastName, 
            Email = account.Email, Username = account.Username, Password = account.Password };

        using (AccountsDbEntities entities = new AccountsDbEntities())
        {
            entities.Account.Add(newAccount);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        return "Success";
    }
```

Is returning this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.'
```

For this line: `entities.Account.Add(newAccount);`

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with ADO.NET Entity

Is my code wrong or is it configuration?

Comment: Related - [Entity Framework ADO.NET Sql.Data.Client provider not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111583/entity-framework-ado-net-sql-data-client-provider-not-found)

Comment: I tried all of that, I've tried everything installing additional packages, removing from machine.config, adding to web.config and app.config nothing works