# Regarding Azure Active Directory Authentication for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, azure-active-directory

In our project we need to implement Active Directory authentication for SQL Server. The project is using the .NET framework, and we are making use of Entity Framework. We are making use of Active Directory service principal in connection string.

I have mentioned the provider as `System.Data.EntityClient` in the EF connection string. I was able to establish connection for ado.net.

This is the normal connection string

```
Server=DemoDB.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=SQLDevDB; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; User Id=*****; Password=*****
```

Here's the Entity Framework connection string

```
metadata=res://*/DemoDB.csdl|res://*/DemoDB.ssdl|res://*/DemoDB.msl;provider=System.Data.EntityClient;provider connection string='{0}'";
```

We get this exception from Entity Framework:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.EntityClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file,or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.'

Please help me with these issues.

Thanks

Comment: Please oh please share your connection string ....

Comment: Below is the normal connection string               
 Server=DemoDB.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=SQLDevDB; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; User Id=*****; Password=*****

Comment: Below is the entity framework connection string

"metadata=res://*/DemoDB.csdl|res://*/DemoDB.ssdl|res://*/DemoDB.msl;provider=System.Data.EntityClient;provider connection string='{0}'";

Comment: @ErikEJ please refer the above connection strings

Comment: [Edit] your question @SaurabhAgrawal . The comments aren't for information that needs to be in the question.

Comment: @ThomA my question is what I  facing the issue

Comment: And you need to [edit] it to add the information that was asked for ,@SaurabhAgrawal . Those comments shouldn't be comments; they **need** to be in the question.

Comment: Try to install the "System.Data.SqlClient" package from nuget Package manager and try to use this as provider.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error while connecting to database.

[image]

I installed `System.Data.SqlClient` from NuGet packet Manager

[image]

My issue resolved after the package installation.

- Make sure register the Entity Framework provider for the `System.Data.SqlClient` SQL connection type.
- Ensure `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` is being copied to the bin directory.

For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111583/entity-framework-ado-net-sql-data-client-provider-not-found).